# Bicep Module Conditional Error when that segment should not execute

Tags: azure-bicep

I am receiving the following error via a YAML pipeline that executes a bicep module:

```
ERROR: InvalidTemplate - Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'res-diag' at line '1' and column '2706' is not valid: The language expression property array index '1' is out of bounds.
```

In summary I am trying to add some diagnostics settings to a firewall, AAD (todo)and SQL to export to an Event Hub.

The Code:

```
@description('Diagnostic name')
param diagnosticName string

@description('Auth ID to allow diags to be saved to Event Hub')
param eventHubAuthorizationRuleId string
@description('Event Hub name')
param eventHubName string

@description('Type of Diagnostic we are trying to create')
@allowed(['Firewall', 'SQLServer', 'AAD'])
param diagnosticType string
@description('Name of Resource we are trying to place the diagnostic on')
param resourceName string

@description('Array of Diagnostic Logs')
param logs array
@description('Array of Diagnostic Metrics')
param metrics array

// Set up Logs
var diagnosticsLogConfig = [for category in logs: {
  category: category
  enabled: true
  retentionPolicy: {
    enabled: true
    days: 28
  }
}]

// Set Up Metrics
var diagnosticsMetricConfig = [for category in metrics: {
  category: category
  enabled: true
  retentionPolicy: {
    enabled: true
    days: 28
  }
}]
// ----------------------------------------------------------------

// Get Scope by Type
resource resourceSQL 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview' existing = if (diagnosticType == 'SQLServer') {
  name: resourceName
}
resource resourceFW 'Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls@2019-04-01' existing = if (diagnosticType == 'Firewall') {
  name: resourceName
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------


// Create Diagnostics by Type
resource diagSQLSetting 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = if (diagnosticType == 'SQLServer')  {
  name: diagnosticName
  scope: resourceSQL
  properties: {
    eventHubAuthorizationRuleId: eventHubAuthorizationRuleId != null ? eventHubAuthorizationRuleId : null
    eventHubName: eventHubName != null ? eventHubName : null
    logs: diagnosticsLogConfig != null ? diagnosticsLogConfig : []
    metrics: diagnosticsMetricConfig != null ? diagnosticsMetricConfig : []
    logAnalyticsDestinationType: 'Dedicated'
  }
}
resource diagFWSetting 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = if (diagnosticType == 'Firewall')  {
  name: diagnosticName
  scope: resourceFW
  properties: {
    eventHubAuthorizationRuleId: eventHubAuthorizationRuleId != null ? eventHubAuthorizationRuleId : null
    eventHubName: eventHubName != null ? eventHubName : null
    logs: diagnosticsLogConfig != null ? diagnosticsLogConfig : []
    metrics: diagnosticsMetricConfig != null ? diagnosticsMetricConfig : []
    logAnalyticsDestinationType: 'Dedicated'
  }
}
```

And the Json:

```
{
    "diagnosticSettings": {
        "value": [
            {
                "diagnosticType": "Firewall",
                "diagnosticName": "my-fw-diag",
                "resourceSubId": "123",             
                "resourceName": "my-fw",
                "resourceRG": "fw-rg",              
                "eventHubName": "my-fw-evh",
                "eventHubAuthorizationRuleId": "/subscriptions/c123/resourcegroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/my-evhns/authorizationrules/RootManageSharedAccessKey",
                "logs": [
                    "AZFWNetworkRule",
                    "AZFWApplicationRule",
                    "AZFWNatRule",
                    "AZFWThreatIntel",
                    "AZFWIdpsSignature",
                    "AZFWDnsQuery",
                    "AZFWFqdnResolveFailure",
                    "AZFWFatFlow",
                    "AZFWFlowTrace",
                    "AZFWApplicationRuleAggregation",
                    "AZFWNetworkRuleAggregation",
                    "AZFWNatRuleAggregation"
                ],
                "metrics": []                   
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Referring back to the Bicep, if I comment the resource segment starting `resource diagSQLSetting 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = if (diagnosticType == 'SQLServer')  {`

The I don't receive the error, but I would have thought that given `SQLServer` doesn't exist in my Json, then this element of code would not be executed beyond a condition check?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've reproduced your error.

The problem is that even though you're conditionally creating the diagnosticSettings for SQLServer, the arm template still needs to be created to cater for both scenarios.

This means that your SQL Server arm template block needs to validate properly, even when the condition isn't met...  (Confusing, eh).

So in your case, all you need to do is refine the scope property to handle the situation when resourceSQL is null (when diagnosticType=='SQLServer').
To do this we can simply just use the ternary operator with the same condition.

```
resource diagSQLSetting 'Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings@2021-05-01-preview' = if (diagnosticType == 'SQLServer')  {
  name: diagnosticName
  //scope:  resourceSQL
  scope: diagnosticType == 'SQLServer' ? resourceSQL : resourceGroup()
```

You should find that this runs fine.

Comment: Worked like a charm Gordon. The odd thing was, this was a test release for Sandbox, On Dev I only had SQL Json and that worked. It had been blowing my mind for a day, but thanks for your efforts and resolution on this. Ray